# Pushing data from one sheet to another based on a condition, without making sheets dependant on one another

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

Trying to see if something like this is possible within Google Sheets.

I have 2 test sheets that are linked with `query(importrange(...`

And I can have Sheet2 updated automatically when a row in sheet 1 matches a value in col C.

What I want to accomplish is update Sheet2 but have it so that if the corresponding data in sheet 1 is deleted, Sheet 2 is not affected. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible by using IMPORTRANGE but you could achieve something similar by using Google Apps Script or and add-on. For details about extending Google Sheets please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Some hints

1. The macro recorder and custom functions could not be used in this case
2. Google Apps Script can't open a spreadsheet on the web browser but it could be used to pass data from one spreadsheet to another.
3. You should think on the logic about how to identify which values will send from "Sheet1" were deleted to keep without affecting "Sheet2". Usually a column holding "keys" a unique identifier for each record (row) could help but it will depend on your data.